# How hide status bar in Tizen Native Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

How to hide status bar in Tizen Native appliation? I could not find it in Tizen Official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use below API with Indicator mode as **ELM_WIN_INDICATOR_HIDE**

```
void elm_win_indicator_mode_set (Evas_Object* obj, Elm_Win_Indicator_Mode mode)
```

Above API Sets the indicator mode of the window.

```
Parameters
 - obj - The window object
 - mode - The mode to set, one of #Elm_Win_Indicator_Mode
```

Ex:

```
elm_win_indicator_mode_set(obj, ELM_WIN_INDICATOR_HIDE)
```